# how to safely unwrap table view cell after the data is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is my `ViewController.swift` noted with comments on the line that errors out.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var sections: [Section] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SectionsData().getSectionsFromData({
            sections in

            self.sections = sections

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
...
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Next line errors out: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.titleLabel!.text = sections[indexPath.section].objects[indexPath.row].name
        cell.datetimeLabel!.text = sections[indexPath.section].objects[indexPath.row].date

        return cell
    }
...
```

And `TableViewCell.swift` with Style `Custom` and cell identifier as `cell`

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var datetimeLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

So `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` is giving nil possibly due to the fact the data is not yet ready to be displayed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is TableViewCell actually a custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Yes it is a custom

Comment: Don't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - you need to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath` as shown in Dan's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an unwrapping issue actually. You've accidentally used `cellForRowAtIndexPath` rather than `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath`.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
```

As [@Eendje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4761181/eendje) pointed out, make sure you register your cell identifier in Interface Builder. Just view your storyboard, click on the cell and update your identifier in Interface Builder.

[image]

Comment: It isn't the need for conditional downcast, it is the fact that the OP is calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` - since they haven't yet returned a cell they are going to get nil.  Their code makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe it's useful to tell her she needs to register the custom cell with an identifier first.

Comment: Thank you @DanBeaulieu and @Paulw11! Yes i registered the cell with identifier `cell`.

Comment: The image is good - I think the `Style` dropdown should be `Custom` as well.

Eg. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tuq8hzfbpydo70/Screenshot%202016-02-11%2012.05.16.png?dl=0

Comment: A link to register identifiers safe and easy (the link is about an `UICollectionView` though), perhaps this could be of any use to her: https://medium.com/@gonzalezreal/ios-cell-registration-reusing-with-swift-protocol-extensions-and-generics-c5ac4fb5b75e#.o9bakwq6p